# Trying to get property of non-object error on object

Tags: php, codeigniter, object

I'm getting the following error reports:

> Severity: Notice
>   Message:
>   Trying to get property of non-object

Using `gettype()` I can see that it's a proper object.

A `print_r()` returns:

```
stdClass Object ( [campaigngroupid] => 3 [name] => And another one [dt_created] => 2014-02-04 17:11:21 [created_userid] => 1 [deleted] => 0 )
```

Echoing out `$object->name` for example works fine, but still, I'm getting this notice...

The object is set using CodeIgniter's `->row()` from a database query result.

All I can ask is, sup?

Comment: can you add your model code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your model, Suppose $query holds the query object:

```
 function some_model_function(){
     ..........
     ..........
     if($query->num_rows() > 0 ){
        return $query->row();
     }
     return FALSE;
 }
```

Also check whether the notice is from any where else.